# XCode5: Old team member now shows No Teams in Organizer

Tags: xcode, ios7, provisioning-profile

I had a few team members in my team of which I am agent/admin. But after a lapse of many months, I find that provisioning profiles messed up. Fixed some of them, but persistent error of one of team members showing "No Teams" in XCode organizer.

What did NOT work so far...
- Close XCode several times, rebooting computer, etc..
- Invite team member, (needed to have member sign in again on separate computer with DevID)
- Wait hours, rebooting Xcode team still did not show up for that member...

I thought it would get fixed up over time .. but it did not!

Answer (score 1):

Found that you have to delete the existing account in team profile. Then add the team member again. Seems there is no way to "refresh" team member settings. Steps below are :

- As agent you login in to developer.apple.com - ios member center with your apple ID
- You have to add the team member by inviting him via Email
- They receive invite email, and accept the invite (better on a separate computer) after signing ID
- Now **this is where the problem occurs** - Even after hours XCode5/organizer does not refresh

**TO GIVE XCode a Kick in the shins ..** 
* XCode > Click on XCode preferences > Accounts tab
* In "old" apple IDs on left, select the one missing your team, Press - to delete it
* Select + and add Apple Id, ask your team member to login (give their password)
* Now like magic they show up as long lost member of your team!